# Sveltekit noImplicitAny keeps appearing back

Tags: javascript, types, sveltekit

I'm working on a non-typescript project using SvelteKit.
No serious stuff, just for some experimental and learning purposes. I decided to go for one monster at a time, and formerly using Svelte + JS, decided to not use Typescript. I thought I declared so during initialisation, but got attacked by VS Code with many "hey, there is an implicit any!" errors.
So I (after some research) decided to add 'noImplicitAny': false in .svelte-kit/types/tsconfig.json

And it helped for a while. After some time (I guess after build?) this setting got overridden and errors are back.

I would appreciate some help with that, need some solution that will stay  with me, at least until I start learning and implementing TypeScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The files in `.svelte-kit` should not be modified, they are all auto-generated. You should be able to create a `tsconfig.json`/`jsconfig.json` at the root of the project to override the settings.

This file should extend the one in `.svelte-kit`:

```json
{
    "extends": "./.svelte-kit/tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": false,
    },
}
```