# How can I globally ignore "Parameter implicitly has an 'any' type" for a JavaScript project in VS Code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, svelte, sveltekit

I have a Svelte/SvelteKit project that is using plain JavaScript, not typescript.

In my `jsconfig.json` file, I have turned on `checkJs` so that VS Code will be able to highlight spelling errors in variable names with a red error line:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "checkJs": true,
      "noImplicitAny": false,
      "paths": {
          "$lib":["./src/lib"],
          "$lib/*":["./src/lib/*"]
      },
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules"],
}
```

However, this is causing a warning (or rather VSCode quick-fix) for every parameter on every one of my functions:

[image]

Bringing my cursor over the yellow `...` under the parameter reveals:

```
Parameter 'value' implicitly has an 'any' type, but a better type may be inferred from usage.js(7044)
```

---

I know that I can 1) add an ignore line in front of every function or 2) add a comment indicating the type to every function. However I don't want to do these.

I would like to disable warnings/vscode quick-fixes globally for this particular type of warning.

Is it possible? Either in `jsconfig.json` or in VS Code?

Comment: cannot reproduce. I don't get a warning. and your screenshot doesn't show problem underlining either. that's quick-fix underlining. and it's not yellow. it's grey. am I missing something?

Comment: @user I may be getting the terminology wrong, this is my first front end project and first time using VSCode. Are you able to reproduce the "quick-fix underlining" with the three dots? Any idea how to disable this particular quick-fix warning globally?

Comment: yes. I get that quick-fix, but not with that message. I get "infer parameter types from usage, which when selected, creates a JSDoc with a [`@type`](https://jsdoc.app/tags-type.html) tag". And I don't know how to disable specific quick fixes. It might not be possible

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sveltekit noImplicitAny keeps appearing back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75054227/sveltekit-noimplicitany-keeps-appearing-back)

Comment: @TobiObeck, no, I already have the noImplicitAny set to false. It seems like this is a VSCode specific "quick fix" as opposed to a js warning.

Comment: quick-fixes generally come from language-specific extensions. In particular, this one is probably related to https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/main/extensions/typescript-language-features, which provides JS and TS intellisense in VS Code using tsserver (part of TypeScript)

Comment: updating the .eslint config